Why isn't my DLL version updated after dotnet publish?
I have a dotnet core project and trying to build from command line using the dotnet publish -c "Release" -p:Version=x.x.x.x command.
I also tested with the following variations of the parameter

-p:Version="x.x.x.x"
/p:Version=x.x.x.x
/p:Version="x.x.x.x"

unfortunately none of them worked.
I also had an AssemblyInfo.cs file in the project. There is no 'Version' node in the .csproj file.
I tried to building with or without the AssemblyVersion attribute, also tried to build without the file, but the 'File version' and 'Product version' of the DLL still remained 0.0.0.0 or the defined value if one was specified in the AssemblyInfo.
How should I build the project to obtain a version number?
Update:
So, as I mentionedI have an AssemblyInfo.cs file. I removed that and also removed the <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo> node from my .csproj file. After that the versioning seems working, but in that case I can't specify the Title, Product, Copyright, etc. properties.

why should it? How should publishing know, which of the version-parts you want to change? Typically you're changing these as part of your build-pipeline.

To change the version numbers, the assembly needs to be compiled again by a build. If the assembly is otherwise up-to-date publish will not build first. If you are changing a .cs source file or the .csproj project file to change the version, that should trigger a build.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain Yes, I want to set the version in a GitLab pipeline, however it doesn't work there either. In local I just give a test value using the -p:Version switch.

@JonathanDodds Yes, I know, I have a publish command in the build pipeline, that's why I'm trying with this and in local before each trial I hit a space or something to trigger the build.

The Version property is expected to be a SemVer value, e.g. it is expected to be "..", NOT "...". You may want to try either -p:Version="x.x.x" or -p:FileVersion="x.x.x.x".

You can directly modify the .csproj file to include <AssemblyVersion>major.minor.build.revision</AssemblyVersion>:
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <!-- Here -->
    <AssemblyVersion>1.2.3.4</AssemblyVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

In Visual Studio, simply double-click on the project to modify the csproj file.
Other settings include:
<FileVersion>a.b.c.d</FileVersion> - similar to AssemblyFileVersionAttribute
<Company>company name</Company> - similar to AssemblyCompanyAttribute
<AssemblyTitle>title here</AssemblyTitle> - similar to AssemblyTitleAttribute
<AssemblyDescription>assembly description here</AssemblyDescription> - similar to AssemblyDescriptionAttribute
